# Slick2D input.isKeyDown

Tags: java, slick2d

Hello I create a code for my game that when you press the key SPACE it run a sprite, but my problem is that I want that when I'm not pressing SPACE the Sprite get restarted (the frame get back to 0)

So I tryed something but it does'nt look like it working. Maybe I did something wrong. If someone could help that would be great.

My code
note: Attacking is a boolean set to false by default and Princess,PrincessBasicAttack and PrincessLeftBasicAttack are three different animations.

```
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_SPACE)){
    Attacking = true;

}
    if (Attacking == true){
         if (right == true) {
             Princess = PrincessBasicAttack;
             Princess.update(delta);
             if (Princess.getFrame() >= Princess.getFrameCount() - 1){
                 Attacking = false;
                 PrincessBasicAttack.setCurrentFrame(0);
                 }
            }
         if (left == true) {
             Princess = PrincessLeftBasicAttack;
             Princess.update(delta);

                if (Princess.getFrame() == Princess.getFrameCount()){
                    Attacking = false;
                }
                if (Attacking == false && Princess.getFrame() != 0){
                    Princess.setCurrentFrame(0);
                }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try calling a restart() method on an animation?

```
if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_SPACE)){
    Attacking = true;
} else {
    PrincessLeftBasicAttack.restart();
    PrincessRightBasicAttack.restart();
}
```

[http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Animation.html#restart()](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Animation.html#restart%28%29)